# VBS InputBox, Output without file extension

Tags: vbscript

I have two prompts, which should be filled out by the users.

The goal is, that the user fills out both prompts, and the output should get the combination of both as a file name.

For example, the User types into the first InputBox "Ryan" and in the second InputBox "Smith". Therefore the output should be a file called "Ryan_Smith", but without a file extension.

Currently it's saved inside a "edit.txt" outputfile, because I don't know how to get it done like I want.

```
Sub MyInputBox()
    Do
        firstNameInput = InputBox("First Name")
    Loop Until firstNameInput <> ""

    Do
        lastNameInput = InputBox("Second Name")
    Loop Until lastNameInput <> ""

    RootFolder = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop")
    MyFile = RootFolder & "\Edit.txt"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(MyFile,ForAppending,True)
    fileStream.WriteLine "First Name: " & firstNameInput
    fileStream.WriteLine "Second Name: " & lastNameInput
    fileStream.WriteLine String(30,"*")
    fileStream.Close
End Sub

Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

Comment: The description for the VB.NET tag EXPLICITLY states that it should not be used for VBScript questions.  Perhaps read the meaning for a tag before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CreateTextFile](http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/vbscript/folder-createtextfile.html) for your purpose.

In example :

```
Sub MyInputBox()
    dim WshShell, firstNameInput, lastNameInput, fso, fileStream, MyFile, RootFolder
    set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Do
        firstNameInput = InputBox("First Name")
    Loop Until firstNameInput <> ""

    Do
        lastNameInput = InputBox("Second Name")
    Loop Until lastNameInput <> ""

    RootFolder = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop")
    MyFile = RootFolder & "\" & firstNameInput & "_" & lastNameInput
    '                         ^------------------------------------^----- Notice this filename creation
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(MyFile)
    fileStream.Close
    set WshShell = nothing
    set fso = nothing
    set fileStream = nothing
End Sub

call MyInputBox()
```